# Different results when not using and using a access modifier with a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm learning java and finally reached that point of getting into inheritance. I learned in the book I'm reading from that it is not necessary to put the "public" access modifier on a method/variable.

```
int showDim() { ... };        // both are the same because by default
public int showDim() { ... }; // not adding an access modifier will make it public.
```

So for a little review on the subject of inheritance with constructors, I created this small program:

**A.java**

```
package Default;

class A extends B {

    A() { System.out.println("A constructor initiated"); }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        A obj = new A();
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
package Default; 

class B {

    B() { System.out.println("B constructor initiated"); }
}
```

When I run the class A main method, this is the result:

```
A constructor initiated
```

Only the A constructor runs. However, when I precede public in front of both the A and B constructor, this is the result.

```
B constructor initiated
A constructor initiated
```

Why does this happen? I thought not adding an access modifier would by default make it public. Any reason for this? only reason I could theorize about is because the main method is running from inside the A class.

Comment: The constructor of the super class is always run, regardless of access modifier. There is no way to prevent this from happening if the code compiles.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it will call the 'public' or 'protected' super() constructor, if it exists. Otherwise it will create an empty one. That's why it gets only the one statement printed in the first case.

Comment: @IvanValeriani it will only create a *default constructor* if no constructor exists. If there is no `super()` constructor for `B()` to call by default, the code won't compile. It doesn't create an empty one in this case, regardless of modifiers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey correct, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> // not adding an access modifier will make it public.

Not true. Not adding an access modifier will give it the `package default` access modifier meaning it is only accessible from within the same class.

[java](/questions/tagged/java) has 4 access modifiers (from most restrictive to less restrictive) :

- `private` : access from same class
- `default` : access from package (you don't need to specify it, `default` is a reserved keyword with another use
- `protected` : access from package and from child classes
- `public` : access from everywhere

---

> When I run the class A main method, this is the result:
>
> A constructor initiated Only the A constructor runs. However, when I
>   precede public in front of both the A and B constructor, this is the
>   result.
>
> B constructor initiated
>
> A constructor initiated

What actually happens is the following

```
A() {
    super(); <--- THIS IS ADDED AT COMPILATION CALLING B's CONSTRUCTOR
    System.out.println("B constructor initiated");
}
```

If you're in a different package, the code will not compile and you'll get the following compilation error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor B() is not visible

    at A.<init>(A.java:7)
    at A.main(A.java:11)
```

The solution of course is to change the constructor's access modifier to `public`

Comment: private is not only for the same class, but also inner classes.

Comment: @IvanValeriani Inner classes are part of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Default public visibility is true only for methods belonging to interfaces, not classes.